# Searching token forward

Tags: search, emacs, elisp

In my .emacs file I have the following function:

```
    ; Search for token forward and backward
    (defun search-token-forward()
      "Search forward for the ucode token at the point."
      (interactive) ; Makes the function available as a command
      (let (target-string)
        (setq target-string (buffer-substring 
                    (+ (re-search-backward "[^A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$]") 1) 
                    (- (re-search-forward "[^A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$]" nil t 2) 1)))
        ; post a message saying what we're looking for
        (message "Search for \`%s\`" target-string)
    ;    (setq case-fold-search nil)
        (search-forward target-string)))
    (global-set-key [f5]           'search-token-forward)

(defun search-token-backward()
  "Search backward for the ucode token at the point."
  (interactive)
  (point)
  (let (target-string)
    (setq target-string (buffer-substring 
                  (+ (re-search-backward "[^A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$]") 1) 
                  (- (re-search-forward  "[^A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$]" nil t 2) 1)))
    (message "backward search for \`%s\`" target-string)
;    (setq case-fold-search nil)
    ;
    ; here the search for the target string is done twice.  Once
    ; for the string that the cursor is on, and once more to go
    ; backwards for the next occurance.  
    ;
    (search-backward target-string nil nil 2)))
    (global-set-key [C-f5]           'search-token-backward)
```

After the first search the cursor moves till after the last character of the expression, which is fine since I can still do "search-token-backward" using another function that I have. Unfortunately, when searching after the last occurrence of the expression, the cursor moves to the end of line and so I can't smoothly try to search backwards since the cursor is not on the expression "position". What is causing this behavior and how is it possible to fix it?

Basically I would like the cursor to stay at the space after the last character of the expression even when there are no forward occurrences of it.

Here is an example:
In the next code while the cursor is on the function foo_func I am clicking f5 which is tied to search-token-forward. The X marks where the cursor is after each click:

```
int foo_func(int w, int y);
       x cursor here to begin with.

some code...

foo_func(1, 2);
        x After first click
some code...   

foo_func(3,4);
        x after second click
some code...

return foo_func(5,6);
               x after third click
```

There are now no more occurences of foo_func in the file, so hitting f5 one 
more time moves the cursor one character to the right, like so:

```
return foo_func(5,6);
                x after forth click, this is the same line above.
```

So I can't simply hit ctrl-f5 to search backward for foo_func because the cursor is no more adjacent to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Record the last successful searched position found (see `match-end`).  Pass `t` as the `NOERROR` arg, and if the return value is `nil` then you know that the string was not found, so you can return to the last successful position (actually, point should still be there).</strike>

Sorry, forget what I said there.  I thought you were having a problem with `search-forward`.  Your problem is no doubt coming up with the target string you are trying to search for.  It's not clear what you really want to search for.  As it is now, you are picking up the buffer text between these two places:

- One char after the first char backward that is not any of these chars: `A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$`.
- One char before the second char forward that is not any of those same chars.

In case of failure, the second search there does not raise an error or advance the cursor from the start position.

I suspect that your current regexp for this is not what you want.  Note, for instance, that it matches newline characters.  Remember that inside `[]` (a character alternative), no characters are special, except `^` if it is first.  See `(elisp) Regexp Special`.

Describe what text you are really trying to pick up from the buffer, to use as your `search-forward` search string (`target-string`).  Specify it in English, and we will help you come up with how to pick it up from the buffer text.  Maybe give an example of typical text that you have in the buffer, showing what part of it you want to pick up, to search for.

*** UPDATE ***

OK, either of these should do what you ask, I guess, but they are pretty ugly.
(The second is a bit more robust.)  You'd probably be better off starting from scratch...

```
 (defun search-token-forward()
   "..."
   (interactive)
   (let* ((opoint            (point))
          (case-fold-search  nil)
          (back              (re-search-backward "[^A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$]"))
          (fwd               (re-search-forward "[^A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$]" nil t 2))
          (target-string     (and back fwd (buffer-substring (+ back 1) (- fwd 1)))))
     (when target-string
       (message "Search for `%s'" target-string)
       (unless (search-forward target-string nil t)
         (goto-char opoint)
         (message "Search failed for `%s'" target-string)))))

 (defun search-token-forward()
   "..."
   (interactive)
   (let* ((opoint            (point))
          (case-fold-search  nil)
          (back              (re-search-backward "[^A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$]"))
          (fwd               (re-search-forward "[^A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$]" nil t 2))
          (target-string     (and back fwd (buffer-substring (+ back 1) (- fwd 1)))))
     (when target-string
       (message "Search for `%s'" target-string)
       (condition-case err
           (search-forward target-string)
         (search-failed (goto-char opoint) (error (error-message-string err)))))))
```

*** UPDATE2 ***

```
 (defun search-token-backward()
   "..."
   (interactive)
   (let ((opoint            (point))
         (case-fold-search  nil)
         back fwd target-string)
     (save-excursion
       (setq back  (re-search-backward "[^A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$]")
             fwd   (re-search-forward "[^A-Za-z0-9/_.@#\$]" nil t 2)))
     (setq target-string  (and back  fwd
                               (buffer-substring (+ back 1) (- fwd 1))))
     (when target-string
       (message "Search for `%s'" target-string)
       (condition-case err
           (search-backward target-string)
         (search-failed (goto-char opoint) (error (error-message-string err)))))))
```

Comment: Drew, I am not proficient in elisp. Could you let me know what needs to change the above code to implement your idea?

Comment: I updated the text as a reply. Don't have an answer for you yet.  It's not clear what you are really searching for.  Once you know what string to search for, `(search-forward target-string)` is, as you thought, all you need.

Comment: Thank for the analysis drew. I actually picked up this piece of code from a coworker's .emacs file. So I am not sure how it is constructed, but it does a very good job finding the next "variable name /structure/ function/macro...etc". I use it mainly in C and assembly code. I think the pattern you see is matching on possible function or variable names in these two languages. For example in C you hardly find "-" being used in function names like in lisp, so there is no such character in the matching pattern.

Comment: It does a great job finding the next matching pattern but the only problem as I mentioned is that it jumps to one character after the last "after" the last match, so you can't go search backward since the cursor is not on the same function/variable.

Comment: Are you sure it is jumping to one char after the last "after" the last match (whatever that means) and not just matching a final newline char? As I said, show examples of the tokens you expect to find and what you expect to skip over and where point ends up instead of what you expect. You have not specified the intended behavior or even described it. (Anyway, why not just use `skip-chars-backward` and `skip-chars-forward` to do such skipping?)

Comment: At any rate, that code cannot be correct in the case where `re-search-forward` fails to find a match, because it return `nil` in that case, and you cannot subtract `1` from `nil`.  In that case, you will get the error `(wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)`.

Comment: Drew, please see the example I provided above. hope that helps understanding the issue.

Comment: Awesome! Yes...that worked flawlessly.
I have updated my question with search-token-backward. I tried to apply the same changes you made to the forward search but did not work out for me.
do you mind also changing the search-token-backward version?
Thanks again!

Comment: OK, I added something for backward.  You can tweak it if necessary from now on.  You can also use the same pattern (`save-excursion`) for forward, and so just combine the two.

Comment: Yup, you got it.
Again, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not debugging your elisp but giving other solutions on how to search a token forward.

**1- Use evil's function**

[Evil-mode](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil) comes with that feature bound to `*`. It calls the function `evil-search-symbol-forward` (VS `…-backward`, bound to `#`).

You can call that function without using evil-mode if you don't want to. Install evil, require it in your ~/.emacs with `(require 'evil)`, do NOT write `(evil-mode 1)` if you don't want to use the mode, then bound your keys to the given functions.

**2- See post on Mastering Emacs**

The author of that blog wrote an equivalent function: http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2013/10/31/smart-scan-jump-symbols-buffer/

Its advantage is that it has got two more features: to replace the symbol in the whole buffer or in the current defun.

ps: `evil-goto-definition` is quite handy too: Go to definition or first occurrence of symbol under point.